# VS 2012 SSIS package forgets 32-bit mod

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis

I have been working on a SSIS package (Visual Studio 2012) the last couple of days. It imports Excel-sheets wherefor I have set the property Run64bitRunTime to False in Debugging tab in the project properties.

But it seems that every now and then (especially after closing/reopening the project) the property is set back to True!

Of course it is just a matter of setting it back again, but does anyone know why this happens and how to change it permanently?

Apart from a bunch of Microsoft products, I have also installed VisualSVN ver. 4.0.9 and JetBrains Resharper ver. 8.2.

(FYI: I am the only one working on this project, so it is not a matter of accidently reimporting an older version from SubVersion).

Comment: For anyone finding this, it doesn't matter what that value is set to. SSDT and BIDS always run in 32bit mode regardless of settings that may say otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this value is NOT "saveable". So it always resets to its "default value". So unfortunately there is not solution, except from remembering to set the value manually each time the project is opened.